# Theming or changing colors for Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, themes

I've got a dark theme for emacs and I use white-on-black for my terminal; to match the color scheme I have going, I'd like to make Nautilus also white-on-black. Is it possible to theme Nautilus or otherwise change the color scheme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can create a custom nautilus.rc (for GTK+ 2.x) or nautilus.css (for GTK+ 3.x).
Unfortunately I do not have a link or instructions on exactly how to theme it, but there are a few themes out there that have these files inside (such as Ambiance and Radiance), and if you take a look at how their definitions for Nautilus are structured, you should be able to work it out pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Since nautilus is gtk, it will use the same theme as the rest of the gnome applications, so you can search for a theme than you like.

The only thing I can think if you don't want to change the gtk theme in the rest of apps, onlyfor nautilus, is create an script than launches nautilus whit a diferent theming:

For example, I use ultimate edition theme in all my gnome, but I don't like how it looks in firefox, so I made a script called "firefox" and put it inside my $HOME/.scripts directory. The script contains just this:

```
#!/bin/bash
env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/New\ Wave\ Dark\ Menus/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/bin/firefox "$@"
```

Now you'll have to make a script called nautilus, and change the word firefox in the script for the route to nautilus executable. And of course change the "New\ Dark\ Menus for the name of a theme you like for nautilus and you have installed in /usr/share/themes

One thing, if the name of the theme contains spaces, you have to put \ before each space so the script recognize the route.

Wish it helps

EDIT:

I forgot to say. If you want to launch that script manually you'll need only to call it, in the directory where it is like this:
First you allow it to run (just needed the first time:

```
chmod +x nautilus
```

Run it:

```
./nautilus
```

But if you want to run nautilus with this script by default, you'll need to create a folder where to put your scripts, save it inside and define that folder as your personal script path:

```
mkdir .scripts
```

Copy the nautilus script inside and give it permisions with

```
chmod +x .scripts/nautilus
```

Set $HOME/.scripts as a PATH:

```
echo "PATH=$HOME/.scripts:$PATH" >> .bash_profile
```

This way, every time nautilus is started it will be started for your personal script.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colour of the main panel by opening **edit** -> **backgrounds and emblems** and dragging  a colour to the main panel

Comment: My nautlius doesn't even have that in Edit (Ubuntu 14.10)

Answer (score 0):

Gnome has a program called [**Gnome Tweaks**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) to configure Gnome.
Gnome Tweaks allows, among other things, to change the *theme*. There is a `Advaita-dark` theme available by default.
Please note that this changes the theme of all the OS, not only Nautilus.

It's possible to install new themes. Here are [some examples](https://omgfoss.com/10-best-gtk-themes-ubuntu-18-04/).